# Checking CKeditor uploaded file

Tags: ckeditor

We're building a blog-like Pylons web application that uses CKeditor and allows to upload images. How can I tell CKeditor that the user attempted an upload that isn't acceptable?
For example, if a user tries to upload an exe instead of an image, I'd like to raise some kind of error and allow the user to recheck what she's trying to upload.
Right now I'm doing the check server-side, but I can't figure out what to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I could return a particular image that explains the problem... I'd love to hear any alternative solution though.

Comment: Sadly no, I just ended up returning an image with a "file is not an image" written on